# Rails tiny_tds symbol lookup error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

Get an error when running a query within a Rails app or console against a SQL Server with tiny_tds.
Note: `gem install tiny_tds` was successful.

Undefined symbol: **rb_thread_blocking_region**

```
../bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: 
/var/www/.../tiny_tds-0.6.2/lib/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so: 
undefined symbol: rb_thread_blocking_region
```

My system setup:

- Centos 7.0
- Ruby 2.2.0p0
- Rails 4.1.4

freetds and freetds-devel are installed:

```
    Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
    Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 4.2
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: yes
```

My MSSQL section of `config/database.yml` looks like (I'm connecting to a remote host):

```
devel_sql:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  dataserver: DBSERVER\DBINSTANCE
  encoding: utf8
  database: SOMEDATABASENAME
  username: xxxx
  password: yyyy
  reconnect: true
  autocommit: true
  timeout: 5000
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem 'pg'
# MSSQL gems
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

The query worked on a Centos 6.3. May any version conflicts?

Comment: It seems one have to wait until `tiny_tds 0.6.3`, I found the discussion here: [link](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/176).
I went back to ruby 2.1.1

Comment: If you found the solution, mark the answer as the correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I verified that tiny_tds 0.6.2 runs with ruby 2.1.1.
ruby 2.2.0 seems not yet to be supported.
Found the discussion [here](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/176).

Answer (score 1):

I am using tiny_tds 0.6.2, ruby 2.2.2, capistrino 3.2.1 and unicorn 4.9.0.

tiny_tds 0.6.2 is not compatible with them. So i changed

```
gem 'tiny_tds', '~> 0.6.3.rc1'
```

and upgraded the tiny_tds and it worked. Hope it works for you and others too.